# Is there a way to deploy Cloud Functions gradually and automatically rollback if something is wrong?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to deploy a cloud function gradually to make it accessible for 1% of api requests at the very beginning and gradually increase this percentage till 100%. Also it would be awesome if this process would stop, if a CF is beginning to throw errors.

Is there way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The GAE admin API has a definition of [`TrafficSplit`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services#TrafficSplit), while this option on the [GCF API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#resource-cloudfunction) does not exist. Furthermore, the concept of having several versions of the same function does not exist at the moment.

The only option you have to do so at the moment would be to manually divide your traffic on the code:

```
exports.helloHttp = (req, res) => {
  if (Math.random() < 0.1){
    res.send(`Hello World!!!`);
  }
  else {
    res.send(`Hello World!!1`);
  }
};
```

And just for the sake of it, there's [this blog post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/03/reliable-releases-and-rollbacks-CRE-life-lessons.html) from the people at GCP explaining why having a proper rollback procedure (and [canary deployments](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-release-canaries-can-save-your-bacon-CRE-life-lessons.html)) it's important, so it's worth a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195) in their tracker.